# No CSS por que a pseudo-classes :empty funciona e a :not(:empty) não funcionam no input?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, input

Estou tentando fazer um modelo de formulário onde penso em melhor a experiencia do usuário dando um feedback visual quando o campo é preenchido. Ai me deparei com um "problema" que não sei explicar...

Porque no `input` a pseudo classe `:empty` funciona, mas a `:not(:empty)` não funciona? Já na `div` os dois funcionam perfeitamente.

Para ilustrar o que eu falo segue o código. Repare que o `input` fica sempre vermelho, mesmo tendo conteúdo dentro. Já na `div` funciona perfeitamente.

```css
input:empty {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
input:not(:empty) {
 border: 2px solid green;
}

div:empty {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
div:not(:empty) {
 border: 2px solid green;
}
div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text" value="content">
<div></div>
<div>content</div>
```

Comment: Resumindo: Acredito que a ideia do `:empty` seja para elementos. Por exemplo, uma div `<div></div>` é `:empty`. No caso, input não tem tag de fechamento, então não faria sentido usar. Se você está tentando verificar o `value`, acho que o caminho seria outro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Não tem verificação nem validação, é só um experimento de UX mesmo... o estranho é que ele aceita o empty, mas não o not:empty... logo o input é sempre empty por ser void? Fiquei meio encucado com isso

Comment: Creio que tem a ver com _tags vazias_, onde o input é um deles.

Comment: @sam desconfio fortemente disso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O elemento input faz parte dos elementos void. Os elementos void são os que não possuem em sua especificação uma tag de fechamento, como por exemplo `<img>` ou `<hr>`. Então estes elementos void serão sempre considerados vazios, mesmo contendo atributos como `value` ou `placeholder`.

O pseudo selector `:empty` será correspondido em:

```
<div></div>

<div><!-- test --></div>
```

Mas não funcionará em:

```
<div> </div>

<div>
  <!-- test -->
</div>

<div>
</div>
```

Você pode tentar dar um feedback para o usuário de outras formas. Uma delas seria usar os seletores `:valid`  e `:invalid` para exibir as cores de forma a chamar a atenção do usuário.

Referências:

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/valid/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/invalid/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica e por contribuir, vc tem a referência de link que fala que todo elemento void é considerado vazio ? Eu queria ler mais a respeito

Comment: Sseria este https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements